# Sinch Disable re-send failed message

Tags: ios, sinch

According to [Sinch document](https://www.sinch.com/docs/instant-message/ios/#sendingamessage), a failure message will be sent again after 12 hours, and stored in the backend for 30 days to download after when clients online.

> Note: Messages are persisted internally in the SDK. In case the
>   message was not sent successfully it will be retried automatically at
>   a later point in time. The message will be retried for 12 hours and
>   then fail permanently firing the failure callback.
>
> Note: Messages are stored in the backend for 30 days before being
>   removed. If the recipient has not started the app and downloaded the
>   message history within this time, the message will be lost and no
>   notification received.

Now, I don't need my message store at Sinch server, and don't need re-send after 12 hours, if my message is sending fail, I want it gone away. How can I do that? I can't find any document related to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way of doing that with our SDK, we keep it for delivery and we do not have presence info.